# Stop IntelliJ from opening SBT tool window automatically

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've just upgraded to IntelliJ 2023.1.2 (build #231.9011.4), and now the SBT tool window opens every time I open a project. Since I almost never need the SBT tool window, this is pretty annoying. I've searched for a setting that would allow me to change this, but with no luck. Anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: Downgrade and wait for update. Scalafmt stopped to work too.